# Why was The Bastard of Istanbul translated into Turkish as "Father and Bastard"?

Tags: translation, title, elif-shafak, the-bastard-of-istanbul

The novel [*The Bastard of Istanbul*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bastard_of_Istanbul) was originally written in English (by a Turkish author, and set largely in the eponymous city in Turkey). It's been translated into various other languages, as listed on the linked Wikipedia page, and usually the title is directly translated. The exception is the Turkish translation, whose title is *Baba ve Piç*, meaning **Father and Bastard**. The translation was done by Aslı Biçen, but presumably the author had a lot of input into it, especially something as important as the title.

## Why was the title changed in the Turkish translation?

Comment: For a book written in English, an Istanbul setting is unusual and attracts my attention (not that I've read it). For a book written in Turkish, it is presumably commonplace.

Comment: Interesting things: the book was originally going to be titled "Baba and the Bastard" in English ([Penguin interview](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/299229/the-bastard-of-istanbul-by-elif-shafak/9780143112716/readers-guide/)), and the book was non-negligibly changed in the Turkish translation, with author input ([Google Books reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=nBxvBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT86&lpg=PT86&dq=The+Bastard+of+Istanbul+title+translation+turkish+why))